# Find triple summation rel in a closed form $S=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sum_{m=1}^{n}\sum_{k=1}^{m}\frac{1}{(n+1)(k+1)(m+1)nmk}$

Tags: calculus, summation, closed-form

> Evaluate $\displaystyle S=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sum_{m=1}^{n}\sum_{k=1}^{m}\frac{1}{(n+1)(k+1)(m+1)nmk}$

My attempt :

Let  $$A=\sum_{k=1}^{m}\frac{1}{k(k+1)} 
=\sum_{k=1}^{m}\left( \frac1{k}-\frac1{k+1} \right) = \frac{m}{m+1}$$

and a second sum :

$$B=\sum_{m=1}^{n}\frac{1}{(m+1)^{2}}$$

from here how I can complete ??

Comment: Switch the order of summation and do the sum in $n$ next.

Comment: A very powerful possible transformation in this case would also be: $\sum_{i_1=a_1}^{b_1}\sum_{i_2=a_2}^{b_2}\sum_{i_3=a_3}^{b_3}{f_1\left(i_1\right)f_2\left(i_2\right)f_3\left(i_3\right)}=\left(\sum_{i=a_1}^{b_1}{f_1\left(i\right)}\right)\left(\sum_{i=a_2}^{b_2}{f_2\left(i\right)}\right)\left(\sum_{i=a_3}^{b_3}{f_3\left(i\right)}\right)$

Comment: @Sudix the bounds depend on each other

Answer (score 9):

Continuing from where you left off, as suggested by Zarrax,
$$
\begin{align}
S&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty{1\over n(n+1)}\sum_{m=1}^n{1\over(m+1)^2}\\
&=\sum_{m=1}^\infty{1\over(m+1)^2}\sum_{n=m}^\infty{1\over n(n+1)}\\
&=\sum_{m=1}^\infty{1\over m(m+1)^2}\\
&=\sum_{m=1}^\infty\left({1\over m}-{1\over m+1}-{1\over(m+1)^2}\right)\\
&=\sum_{m=1}^\infty\left({1\over m}-{1\over m+1}\right)-\sum_{m=1}^\infty{1\over(m+1)^2}\\
&=1-\left({\pi^2\over6} -1\right)\\
&=2-{\pi^2\over6}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: @saulstpatz Thank youso much!

Comment: @EllenEllen It was my pleasure.

Comment: if I have fourth summation in same just added $\sum_{p=1}^{k}\frac{1}{p(p+1)}$ then I use same method and order sum ?

Comment: You can try it, but you'll probably end up with a product whose value isn't known in closed form.  Exact values of $\zeta(k)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{-k}$ are known when $k$ is an even positive integer, but not when $k$ is odd.  You may be able to get an answer in terms of $\zeta(3)$, though.  Give it a shot.

Comment: OK my friend @saulspatz I will try , thanks aging

Comment: Using my approach, it is fairly clear that the generalization to 4 sums will not involve $\zeta(3)$, as those terms telescope. On the other hand, you get a $\zeta(4)$ term.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt I'll have to look at your approach more closely.  Last night, I was confused by how you were counting the terms, but it was pretty late.  Maybe it will be clearer in the morning.

Comment: I've added examples that might make it clearer.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt Thanks, but I figured it out.  A night's sleep and a cup of tea work wonders.

Answer (score 6):

A completely alternative approach can be *summed* up by writing the entire thing as a "single" sum:

$$S=\sum_{1\le k\le m\le n}f(k)f(m)f(n);\quad f(j)=\frac1{j(j+1)}$$

Notably, the summand is symmetric in $k,m,n$ i.e. swapping any two variables does not change the result. Using this, we can rewrite the summand with the bounds $(1\le m\le k\le n)$ or $(1\le n\le k\le m)$ etc. There are $3!=6$ ways to rearrange the bounds, but they all result in $S$. Adding every possible combination together thus gives us

$$6S=\sum_{k\ge1}\sum_{m\ge1}\sum_{n\ge1}f(k)f(m)f(n)+3\sum_{a\ge1}\sum_{b\ge1}f(a)f(b)^2+2\sum_{j\ge1}f(j)^3$$

The first triple series results from covering every possible $(k,m,n)$, since each $(k,m,n)$ must satisfy $(k\le m\le n)$ or some rearrangement of this. Then we have an extra double series for when two of the variables are equal, which has 6 possibilities, 3 of which are covered in the triple series. The last series comes about when all three variables are equal, which has 6 possibilities, 4 of which are given by the triple and double series.

Since all the indices are independent now, this is just a matter of doing some partial fractions and working each out. We have, from your work:

$$\sum_{n\ge1}f(n)=1$$

For the squared term, we have:

\begin{align}\sum_{n\ge1}f(n)^2&=\sum_{n\ge1}-\frac2n+\frac2{n+1}+\frac1{n^2}+\frac1{(n+1)^2}\\&=-\frac21-\frac1{1^2}+\sum_{n\ge1}\frac2{n^2}\\&=-3+\frac{\pi^2}3\end{align}

For the cubed term, we have:

\begin{align}\sum_{n\ge1}f(n)^3&=\sum_{n\ge1}\frac6n-\frac6{n+1}+\frac1{n^3}-\frac1{(n+1)^3}-\frac3{n^2}-\frac3{(n+1)^2}\\&=\frac61+\frac1{1^3}+\frac3{1^2}-\sum_{n\ge1}\frac6{n^2}\\&=10-\pi^2\end{align}

which finally results in

$$6S=1^3+3(1)\left(-3+\frac{\pi^2}3\right)+2(10-\pi^2)=12-\pi^2$$

> $$S=2-\frac{\pi^2}6$$

---

### More explicit explanation

Let us define

$$S_1=\sum_{k,m,n\ge1}f(k)f(m)f(n)$$

$$S_2=\sum_{k,m\ge1}f(k)f(m)^2$$

$$S_3=\sum_{k\ge1}f(k)^3$$

It should be pretty clear that $f(k)f(m)f(n)$ should occur 6 times in our $6S$. We will tackle this case-by-case.

Consider the case of $k<m<n$. As an example, consider $f(1)f(2)f(3)$. How many times does this appear in $S_1$? Notice that it occurs for

$$(k,m,n)\in\{(1,2,3),(1,3,2),(2,1,3),(2,3,1),(3,1,2),(3,2,1)\}$$

and every combination occurs in $S_1$.

Consider the case of $k\ne m=n$. As an example, consider $f(1)f(2)f(2)=f(1)f(2)^2$. How many times does this appear in $S_1$? Notice that it occurs for

$$(k,m,n)\in\{(1,2,2),(2,1,2),(2,2,1)\}$$

which is missing $3$ cases. The other $3$ case comes from $S_2$.

Consider the case of $k=m=n$. As an example, consider $f(1)f(1)f(1)=f(1)^3$. How many times does this appear in $S_1$? Notice it occurs only once, for $(k,m,n)=(1,1,1)$. How many times does this appear in $S_2$? It also occurs only once, for $(k,m)=(1,1)$. We multiply the $S_2$ by 3, which gives us 4 cases covered in total. We fill this in with 2 copies of $S_3$. This finally leaves us with

$$S=S_1+3S_2+2S_3$$

Comment: Thank you very much , if we have ? $S=\sum_{1≤k≤m≤j≤n}f(m)f(n)f(k)f(j)$ then $24S=?$

Comment: You would get$$24S=\sum_{j,k,m,n\ge1}f(j)f(k)f(m)f(n)+12\sum_{j,k,m\ge1}f(j)f(k)f(m)^2+12\sum_{j,k\ge1}f(j)^2f(k)^2+12\sum_{j,k\ge1}f(j)f(k)^3+10\sum_{j\ge1}f(j)^4$$if I did it right.

Comment: please check ? I need it

Comment: What do you think about answer if fourth summation =?

Comment: @EllenEllen If you have another problem, you should ask another question.

Comment: @saulspatz i need learn  this method ? How work , If I understand it I will solve any similar problems ?

Comment: @EllenEllen The best way to do that is to try it for yourself.  This site is intended to build up a base of questions and answers that people who have similar problems can search, but the search doesn't extend to comments.  So, I suggest you try the problem for yourself.  If you have trouble, ask another question, including a link back to this question.

Comment: @saulspatz I'm sorry sir OK , I will post another question don't forget we all learning from other .

Comment: @EllenEllen I'm not scolding you, just trying to acquaint you with the customs on this site.

Comment: @saulspatz yes! I know sir thank for your advice

Comment: @EllenEllen I've updated my answer to include more examples.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt see this post    https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3294936/some-identity-of-summation-and-generalization  and your formula of fourth sums correct ?

Answer (score 2):

Yet another way:
$$\sum_{1\leq k<m<n}\frac{1}{kmn(k+1)(m+1)(n+1)} = [x^3]\prod_{h\geq 1}\left(1+\frac{x}{h(h+1)}\right)=\frac{1}{\pi}[x^4]\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\sqrt{1-4x}\right)$$
where the first equality follows from Viète's theorem and the second one from the Weierstrass product for the cosine function. The Maclaurin series of the RHS immediately leads to
$$\sum_{1\leq k<m<n}\frac{1}{kmn(k+1)(m+1)(n+1)} = 5-\frac{\pi^2}{2} $$
and we may deal with the cases $k=m$ or $m=n$ in a similar fashion.

Answer (score 1):

Continuing from the calculation above we have to sum:

$$S=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n(n+1)}\sum_{m=1}^n\frac{1}{(m+1)^2}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{H_2(n+1)-1}{n(n+1)}\\=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}[\frac{H_2(n+1)}{n}-\frac{H_2(n+1)}{n+1}]-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n(n+1)}$$

Using the identity $H_2(n+1)=H_2(n)+\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}$

$$S=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}[\frac{H_2(n)}{n}-\frac{H_2(n+1)}{n+1}]-1+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n(n+1)^2}$$

And since the first sum telescopes to $1$ and the identity $\frac{1}{n(n+1)^2}=\frac{1}{n(n+1)}-\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}$ holds we obtain that:

$$S=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n(n+1)^2}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\Big[\frac{1}{n(n+1)}-\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}\Big]=1-(\zeta(2)-1)=2-\frac{\pi^2}{6}$$

Comment: Thanks! $+1)$ beautiful solution

Answer (score 1):

*Just for your curiosity.*

We could also have a cloased form for the partial sum
$$S_p=\sum_{n=1}^{p}\sum_{m=1}^{n}\sum_{k=1}^{m}\frac{1}{(n+1)(k+1)(m+1)nmk}$$since
$$\sum_{k=1}^{m}\frac{1}{(n+1)(k+1)(m+1)nmk}=\frac{1}{(m+1)^2 n (n+1)}$$
$$\sum_{m=1}^{n}\frac{1}{(m+1)^2 n (n+1)}=\frac{\pi ^2-6-6 \psi ^{(1)}(n+2)}{6 n (n+1)}$$
$$S_p=\sum_{n=1}^{p}\frac{\pi ^2-6-6 \psi ^{(1)}(n+2)}{6 n (n+1)}=\frac{12 (p+1)-\pi ^2 (p+2)+6 (p+2) \psi ^{(1)}(p+2)}{6 (p+1)}$$

Now, using, for large values of $q$, the expansion
$$\psi ^{(1)}(q)=\frac{1}{q}+\frac{1}{2 q^2}+\frac{1}{6 q^3}+O\left(\frac{1}{q^5}\right)$$ and continuing with Taylor series for large values of $p$
$$S_p=\left(2-\frac{\pi ^2}{6}\right)+\frac{1-\frac{\pi ^2}{6}}{p}+\frac{\pi ^2-3}{6
   p^2}-\frac{2+\pi ^2}{6 p^3}+\frac{10+\pi ^2}{6 p^4}+O\left(\frac{1}{p^5}\right)$$

For illustration purposes, using $p=10$, the exact value is
$$S_{10}=\frac{42308191}{140873040}\approx 0.300328$$ while the above truncated expansion gives
$$\frac{125690-10909 \pi ^2}{60000}\approx    0.300375$$

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
$\ds{\mbox{Evaluate}\
\bbox[15px,#ffd]{S \equiv \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\sum_{m = 1}^{n}
\sum_{k = 1}^{m}{1 \over \pars{n + 1}\pars{k + 1}\pars{m + 1}nkm}}}$

---

\begin{align}
S & \equiv \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\sum_{m = 1}^{n}
\sum_{k = 1}^{m}{1 \over \pars{n + 1}\pars{k + 1}\pars{m + 1}nkm}
\\ & =
\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{1 \over n\pars{n + 1}}\sum_{m = 1}^{n}
{1 \over m\pars{m +1}}\
\overbrace{\sum_{k = 1}^{m}{1 \over k\pars{k + 1}}}^{\ds{m \over m + 1}}
\\ &=
\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{1 \over n\pars{n + 1}}\sum_{m = 1}^{n}
{1 \over \pars{m + 1}^{2}} =
\sum_{m = 1}^{\infty}{1 \over \pars{m + 1}^{2}}\
\overbrace{\sum_{n = m}^{\infty}{1 \over n\pars{n + 1}}}^{\ds{1 \over m}}
\\[5mm] & =
\sum_{m = 0}^{\infty}{1 \over \pars{m + 1}\pars{m + 2}^{2}} =
\left.-\,\totald{}{\alpha}
\sum_{m = 0}^{\infty}{1 \over \pars{m + 1}\pars{m + \alpha}}
\right\vert_{\ \alpha\ =\ 2}
\\[5mm] & =
-\,\totald{}{\alpha}\bracks{\Psi\pars{\alpha} - \Psi\pars{1} \over
\alpha - 1}
_{\ \alpha\ =\ 2}
\end{align}

$\ds{\Psi}$ is the [Digamma Function](http://people.math.sfu.ca/%7Ecbm/aands/page_258.htm) and
$\ds{\Psi\pars{1} = -\gamma}$ where $\ds{\gamma}$ is the
[Euler-Mascheroni Constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Mascheroni_constant)

Then,
\begin{align}
S & \equiv \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\sum_{m = 1}^{n}
\sum_{k = 1}^{m}{1 \over \pars{n + 1}\pars{k + 1}\pars{m + 1}nkm}
\\[5mm] & =
\underbrace{\Psi\pars{2}}_{\ds{1 - \gamma}}\ +\ \gamma -
\underbrace{\Psi\, '\pars{2}}_{\ds{{\pi^{2} \over 6} - 1}} =
\bbox[15px,#ffd,border:1px solid navy]{2 - {\pi^{2} \over 6}}\
\approx 0.3551
\end{align}

---

Note that $\ds{\Psi\pars{2}}$ is evaluated with its
[recursive property $\ds{\bf\color{black}{6.3.5}}$](http://people.math.sfu.ca/%7Ecbm/aands/page_258.htm). Namely, $\ds{\Psi\pars{2} =
\Psi\pars{\color{red}{1} + 1} = \Psi\pars{\color{red}{1}} +
{1 \over \color{red}{1}} = -\gamma + 1}$.

In addition ( [see $\ds{\ \bf\color{black}{6.3.16}}$](http://people.math.sfu.ca/%7Ecbm/aands/page_259.htm) ):
$\ds{\Psi\, '\pars{2} =
\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{1 \over \pars{n + 1}^{2}} =
\sum_{n = 2}^{\infty}{1 \over n^{2}} =
\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{1 \over n^{2}} - {1 \over 1^{2}} =
{\pi^{2} \over 6} - 1}$.