# some identity of summation and generalization

Tags: calculus, probability, summation, closed-form

I see this way and idea from Simply Beautiful Art

profile [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/272831/simply-beautiful-art)

Let : $S=\displaystyle\sum_{1≤k≤m≤n≤\infty}f(m)f(k)f(n)$

then :

$6S=\displaystyle\sum_{n,m,k≥1}f(m)f(k)f(n)+3\displaystyle\sum_{n,m≥1}f(m)f^{2} (n)+2\sum_{n≥1}f^{3}(n)$

See images

now let : $A=\displaystyle\sum_{1≤i≤≤k≤j≤m≤\infty}f(m)f(k)f(j)f(i)$

then $24A=?$

I need understand this brilliant  way

[image][image]

Answer (score 1):

There are $4!=24$ permutations of $f(m)f(k)f(j)f(i)$, so we will always need to end up with 24 combinations by adding the following sums:

\begin{align}S_1&=\sum_{m,k,j,i\ge1}f(m)f(k)f(j)f(i)\\S_2&=\sum_{k,j,i\ge1}f(k)f(j)f(i)^2\\S_3&=\sum_{j,i\ge1}f(j)^2f(i)^2\\S_4&=\sum_{j,i\ge1}f(j)f(i)^3\\S_5&=\sum_{i\ge1}f(i)^4\end{align}

---

Consider the case of all distinct values i.e. $m<k<j<i$. All 24 combinations are then contained within $S_1$.

---

Consider the case of 3 distinct values i.e. $m=i$ and $j,k$ are distinct. For example, consider $f(1)f(2)f(3)^2$. This appears 12 times in $S_1$ as

$$(m,k,j,i)\in\left.\begin{cases}(1,2,3,3),(1,3,2,3),(1,3,3,2),(2,1,3,3),(2,3,1,3),(2,3,3,1),\\(3,1,2,3),(3,1,3,2),(3,2,1,3),(3,2,3,1),(3,3,1,2),(3,3,2,1))\end{cases}\right\}$$

and in $S_2$, they appear 2 times as

$$(k,j,i)\in\{(1,2,3),(2,1,3)\}$$

and since this leaves us with 12 combinations to reach 24, we need 6 copies of $S_2$.

---

Consider the case of 2 distinct values with 2 variables for each value i.e. $m=i\ne k=j$. For example, consider $f(1)^2f(2)^2$. There are 6 ways for this to appear in $S_1$:

$$(m,k,j,i)\in\{(1,1,2,2),(1,2,1,2),(1,2,2,1),(2,1,1,2),(2,1,2,1),(2,2,1,1)\}$$

and 2 ways for this to appear in $S_2$:

$$(k,j,i)\in\{(1,1,2),(2,2,1)\}$$

and 2 ways for this to appear in $S_3$:

$$(j,i)\in\{(1,2),(2,1)\}$$

and since we have 6 copies of $S_2$, this leaves us with 6 remaining combinations to reach 24, hence we have 3 copies of $S_3$.

---

Consider the case of 2 distinct values with 1 and 3 variables for each i.e. $j\ne m=k=i$.  For example, consider $f(1)f(2)^3$. This appears 4 ways in $S_1$:

$$(m,k,j,i)\in\{(1,2,2,2),(2,1,2,2),(2,2,1,2),(2,2,2,1)\}$$

and 2 ways in $S_2$:

$$(k,j,i)\in\{(1,2,2),(2,1,2)\}$$

and no ways in $S_3$ and only 1 way in $S_4$. This leaves us with 8 more, hence we have 8 copies of $S_4$.

---

Consider the case of all equal variables i.e. $m=k=j=i$. For example, consider $f(1)^4$. This appears exactly once in every sum, which thus leaves us with 12 copies of $S_5$.

---

Hence we have

> $$24S=S_1+6S_2+3S_3+8S_4+12S_5$$